# CDH5 Hue Hive — Beeswax Server: Error opening session: Failed to validate proxy privilage of hue for admin

Tags: hadoop, hive, hue, apache-sentry

I setup a Hadoop cluster with security by Kerberos, Hive has been enable Sentry. And I have problem with Hue - Hive (Beeswax) Editor. Hue can't load  data, information from hive, in hive-server2 log :

```
  2014-04-03 11:36:39,814 WARN  thrift.ThriftCLIService (ThriftCLIService.java:GetSchemas(364)) - Error getting catalogs:
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Invalid SessionHandle: SessionHandle [de47ccb1-0bf0-44f0-b15b-c07fd62b1134]
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.SessionManager.getSession(SessionManager.java:156)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.getSchemas(CLIService.java:222)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.GetSchemas(ThriftCLIService.java:359)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$GetSchemas.getResult(TCLIService.java:1433)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$GetSchemas.getResult(TCLIService.java:1418)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge20S$Server$TUGIAssumingProcessor.process(HadoopThriftAuthBridge20S.java:603)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:244)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2014-04-03 11:36:39,815 INFO  thrift.ThriftCLIService (ThriftCLIService.java:OpenSession(203)) - Client protocol version: HIVE_CLI_SERVICE_PROTOCOL_V5
2014-04-03 11:36:39,816 WARN  thrift.ThriftCLIService (ThriftCLIService.java:OpenSession(212)) - Error opening session:
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Failed to validate proxy privilage of hue for admin
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.getProxyUser(ThriftCLIService.java:556)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.getUserName(ThriftCLIService.java:236)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.getSessionHandle(ThriftCLIService.java:242)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.OpenSession(ThriftCLIService.java:206)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$OpenSession.getResult(TCLIService.java:1313)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$OpenSession.getResult(TCLIService.java:1298)
    at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge20S$Server$TUGIAssumingProcessor.process(HadoopThriftAuthBridge20S.java:603)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:244)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.AuthorizationException: Unauthorized connection for super-user: hue from IP /10.199.91.97
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.authorize.ProxyUsers.authorize(ProxyUsers.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure.authorizeProxyAccess(HadoopShimsSecure.java:585)
    at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.getProxyUser(ThriftCLIService.java:552)
    ... 12 more
```

Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Is Hive impersonation turned on? When using Sentry it should be off that way the Hive user can access the data according to Sentry privileges. This [Hive with Sentry](http://gethue.com/hadoop-tutorial-hive-query-editor-with-hiveserver2-and/) post details it more.

Comment: Hi Romain, Hive impersonation has been turn off before.

When I use cmd beeline, everything is ok. But when I use Hue, I cann't connect to Hive. I saw this document: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-5155 and is trying to fix this issue. Did you know it?

Comment: "Failed to validate proxy privilage of hue for admin" I try to fix this issue.

I have this config in core-site.xml:

  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.hosts</name>
  <value>*</value>

  <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.groups</name>
  <value>*</value>

  
But it can't fix, i think it work with "impersonation"

Comment: I had a similar problem, but  without Sentry. Beeline was working and the conf was fine, however from hue it was failing. Killing the hiveserver2 process manually & restarting it from Ambari solved it.